# Use ExcelLibrary DataSetHelper on hosting

Tags: c#

I have that work on local but not in hosting because of the path. What do I need to change? I use Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments that return c: on local but on hosting do this error: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\CallTool\Files\prospect_636652254790345267.xls'

```
        string MyDocPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        string pathDirectory = MyDocPath + "/CallTool/Files/";
        if (!Directory.Exists(pathDirectory))
        {
            try
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(pathDirectory);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                rStr = "Erreur creation folder :" + ex.Message;
            }
        }
            ExcelLibrary.DataSetHelper.CreateWorkbook(Path.Combine(pathDirectory, fileName + ".xls"), ds);

        rStr = string.Format(@"The file {0} has been genered in {1} ", fileName, pathDirectory);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        rStr = "Erreur :"+e.Message;
    }

    return rStr;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Server.MapPath and create a folder on your server say Files
and store there
on server u don't get access to documents

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the file somewhere that DOES exist.. perhaps a "Downloads" or "Uploads" directory relative to your site root.